# PBS_Server: LOG_ERROR::Unknown node (15064) in set_nodes, request failed, corrupt request

Tags: pbs, torque

I have installed Torque 4.2.6 as it supports GPUs.

Whenever I submitted a job, it is not executed, always it remains in the queue.

My script is

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1:gpus=1
#PBS -l walltime=00:30:00
#PBS -q batch
#PBS -o $HOME/out_$PBS_JOBID
#PBS -e $HOME/err_$PBS_JOBID
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m bae
#PBS -V

echo PBS JOB id is $PBS_JOBID
echo PBS_NODEFILE is $PBS_NODEFILE
echo PBS_QUEUE is $PBS_QUEUE

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

echo `hostname`
date

./prefixsum
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
PBS_Server: LOG_ERROR::Unknown node  (15064) in set_nodes, request failed, corrupt request
```

If the above script is wrong, can anyone tell how to write a script to execute job on GPUs

**EDIT**

I found below errors in /var/log/messages

```
PBS_Server: LOG_ERROR::Unknown node  (15064) in set_nodes, request failed, corrupt request
PBS_Server: LOG_ERROR::node_spec, job requesting nodes that will never be available - spec = 1:ppn=1:gpus=1
PBS_Server: LOG_ERROR::node_spec, job requesting nodes that will never be available - spec = PÂºtÃ;
```

Pbsnodes -a

```
 node01
 state = free
 np = 32
 ntype = cluster
 status =     rectime=1397191125,varattr=,jobs=,state=free,netload=10273233433,gres=,loadave=2.28,ncpus=32,physmem=132092224kb,availmem=180232352kb,totmem=197628216kb,idletime=148596,nusers=4,nsessions=12,sessions=3914 3918 3920 3945 3947 3971 13227 13989 14012 17037 28460 28766,uname=Linux node01 2.6.32-401.el6.rhbz988052_minimal.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 30 18:39:08 EDT 2013 x86_64,opsys=linux
 mom_service_port = 15002
 mom_manager_port = 15003
 gpus = 1
 gpu_status = gpu[0]=gpu_id=0000:84:00.0;gpu_product_name=Tesla K20m;gpu_display=Disabled;gpu_pci_device_id=102810DE;gpu_pci_location_id=0000:84:00.0;gpu_fan_speed=N/A;gpu_memory_total=4799 MB;gpu_memory_used=11 MB;gpu_mode=Exclusive_Thread;gpu_state=Unallocated;gpu_utilization=99 %;gpu_memory_utilization=6 %;gpu_ecc_mode=Enabled;gpu_single_bit_ecc_errors=0;gpu_double_bit_ecc_errors=0;gpu_temperature=29 C,driver_ver=319.49,timestamp=Fri Apr 11 10:08:44 2014
```

Comment: Are there any error messages from node_spec()?

Comment: Also, can you include the pbsnodes output for a node that has gpus?

Comment: @dbeer: As you asked I have included error message from node_spec() and output of pbsnodes

Comment: Are there any other error messages in the vicinity? It looks like somehow the specification string's memory is getting corrupted.

Comment: No other errors. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Today I found one more error along with the above errors. i.e.,     pbs_server: LOG_ERROR::kill_job_on_mom, stray job 143.node found on node01

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue but I can't. I'm able to run a gpu job on 4.2.6 without issue. 2 things: what scheduler are you using? and what happens if you try to run the job manually? Something like: qrun <jobid> -H <hostname that has gpus>:ppn=1:gpus=1

Comment: I'm using pbs_sched with FIFO scheduling policy. I'm able to run the job using qrun. But what is the problem with qsub?

Comment: So you're saying it works if you manually run it with qrun, but if you allow pbs_sched to run it you get this failure? That is strange. Have you tried setting up Maui? Maui is a bit more robust of a scheduler than pbs_sched and might not have the same bug, and has quite a few more features than pbs_sched.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file *nodes* properly written? It should be in *server_priv*

It seems that Torque doesn't know where to send the job.

Comment: nodes file is properly written. If I submit a job to CPU then it is working properly. If I submit job to the GPU then it is throwing above mentioned errors.